# Cannot import Tornado submodules

Tags: python, tornado

Trying to install Tornado for first time (On EC2 Linux instance). I did

```
pip install tornado
```

and then tried running the hello world example: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/#hello-world

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(80)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I then try:

```
python hello.py
```

but get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "testing/tornado.py", line 1, in 
>       import tornado.ioloop   File "/opt/pdf_engine/testing/tornado.py", line 1, in 
>       import tornado.ioloop ImportError: No module named ioloop

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Don't name your file `tornado.py`; it shadows the actual Tornado import. Name it something like what you used in your example, e.g. `hello.py`

Right now, your `import tornado.ioloop` is trying to import the member `ioloop` from your own file, because it's named `tornado` and in the current directory which has the highest import precedence.

Comment: How to stop the server. I also tried hello world example. But I don't know how to stop it

Comment: Try `Ctrl+C` to stop it.

Comment: And it's highly probable that you have to remove the tornado.pyc that was generated

Comment: +1 On some answers I really wish I could apply more than just one upvote!

Comment: its fake solution :(

Comment: You just gotta love python modules :(

Answer (score 2):

If you named your file tornado.py and rename it to another name,don't forget to remove tornado.pyc in your directory.